# jQuery: set/unset active links

Tags: jquery

I have a set of links (same URL).  I'd like to make the following changes to the "li" element when its associate link is clicked:

1) Add a class='active' to li element.

2) Remove the "a" anchor, and keep only the "span" element.

**HTML before jQuery:**

```
<ul class="navbar-list">
   <li><a href='#' data-id="1" > <span>Link 1</span></a> </li>
   <li><a href='#' data-id="2" > <span>Link 2</span></a> </li>
   <li><a href='#' data-id="3" > <span>Link 3</span></a> </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('ul.navbar-list li a').on('click', function() {
$(this).parent("li").addClass('active');          
$("ul.navbar-list li.active a").contents().unwrap();});
```

**HTML after jQuery (assume the first link is clicked):**

```
<ul class="navbar-list">
   <li class='active'><span>Link 1</span></li>
   <li><a href='#' data-id="2" > <span>Link 2</span></a> </li>
   <li><a href='#' data-id="3" > <span>Link 3</span></a> </li>
</ul>
```

Question:

I need to reset and remove the above behaviors when another link is clicked (I want link 1 to have "active" class removed, and anchor restored).  What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the index and the html of the clicked element before add `active` class to it and next time you click on another one, it can be restored.

Here's a demo:

```js
let temp = null;

$('ul.navbar-list').on('click', 'li a', function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  let $parent = $this.parent("li");

  if (temp != null) {
    $('ul.navbar-list li')[temp.index].outerHTML = temp.html;
  }

  temp = {
    index: $parent.index(),
    html: $parent[0].outerHTML
  };

  $parent.addClass('active');
  $this.contents().unwrap();
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navbar-list">
  <li>
    <a href='#' data-id="1"> <span>Link 1</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' data-id="2"> <span>Link 2</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#' data-id="3"> <span>Link 3</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply!  It helped me understand my problem and provided a solution to fix it.  Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.